# How to use python to read an encrypted folder

Tags: python, c, encryption, directory

I want to design an application that reads some a folder of text files and shows the user its contents. Three problems arise: I need the folder containing the text files to be encrypted which I don't know how to do, two, I need a way to read the encrypted files without revealing the key in the python code, so I guess C would be the best way to do that even if I don't like that way(any suggestions are welcome,using python if possible), and three, I need a way to add files to the folder and then send the encrypted folder along with the program.
Is there any way to do those things without ever revealing the key or giving the user the possibility to read the folder except using my program?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT:**  Also, is there a way to use C to encrypt and decrypt files so that I can put the key in the compiled file and distribute that with my program?

Comment: If you are trying to prevent your users from reading the files you plan on giving them, just give up now; if the program is worth useing, *someone* will break any obscurity you try to add. (If you aren't, then sorry for the mini-rant; the first and/or last thirds of @schmatz's answer are probably the best solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best thing to do would be to encrypt the individual text files using GPG, one of the strongest encryption systems available(and for free!) You can get several python libraries to do this, and I recommend python-gnupg. Also, you can probably just reference the file where the key is located and distribute it along with the application? If you want to include a preset key and not have your users be able to see where that key is, you are going to have a very hard time. How about using a key on a server you control that somehow only accepts requests for the key from copies of your application? I don't know how you'd make this secure though through Python.

About adding files to the folder and sending it along with the program, perhaps you aren't thinking of the most optimal solution? There are plenty of python data structures that can be serialized and accomplish most of the things you are talking about in your post.

Comment: Can you please give an example of the python data structures you were talking about in your answer?

Comment: @nicotranquil, [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) should work for most objects, and I think you can add custom handling for anything the default serialization won't work for.